# Cannot run camera_calibration

Tags: calibration, stereo, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Why can't I run the camera calibration? I am using diamondback in Ubuntu 10.10. I get the ff:

```
Waiting for service /stereo/left/set_camera_info ...
Service not found
Waiting for service /stereo/right/set_camera_info ...
Service not found
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9453/cannot-run-camera_calibration/) by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 475 on 2011-03-16

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Eric Perko](https://answers.ros.org/users/14/eric-perko/) on 2011-03-16**:
Can you post the output of "rosservice list" while your stereo driver is running and which stereo driver you are using?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I already found it, remapped the ff: `right_camera:=/stereo/right left_camera:=/stereo/left` to this: `right_camera:=/right left_camera:=/left`

---

Originally posted by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) with karma: 475 on 2011-03-16

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Homer Manalo](https://answers.ros.org/users/74/homer-manalo/) on 2011-03-16**:
Can someone check this? I cannot check it myself, thanks

**Comment by [ZoltanS](https://answers.ros.org/users/4436/zoltans/) on 2013-05-15**:
Could you please share what driver did you use and maybe your .launch files? I am trying to make it work with the usb_cam driver in groovy, but I always get the same errors.